# git apply three way merge

Tags: git, patch

I have a question about applying patch which contains conflicts with working copy. I am a bit confused by `git apply` as it sometimes applies patch and creates conflict markers and sometimes it does it only when I specify `--3way` (if I don't specify `--3way` it says that patch can't be applied and does nothing). Does this behaviour depend on some global settings?

Git version: `1.8.1.1`

Comment: Same here. `git apply -3` calaims to have succeeded with a conflict, but no action is taken at all. Is there still no solution? Are old patch files just useless?

Answer (score -1):

May be a better approach is merging the new branch with your working branch. If your working branch is master, here is an example:

- merge master branch to new-features branch

  ```
  git checkout new-branch
  git merge master
  ```
- merge new-features branch to master

  ```
  git checkout master
  git merge -s theirs
  ```

You can read more here [Merge repos while overwriting changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466802/merge-repos-while-overwriting-changes/15430168)

Comment: You talk about merging branches, however I have patches. For example I need to merge patch into working copy when I restore stashed changes and they do not apply cleanly.